# Javascript hover to click

Tags: javascript

Well, I've got this javascript code to open and close a login tab on my website:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#vale_presente_info').tooltip();
    $('#top-login').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).children('#top-login-over:hidden').slideDown(100);
        },
        function(){
            $('#top-login-over:visible').slideUp(100);
        }
    );
    $('#top-login').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).children('#top-login-over-logged:hidden').slideDown(100);
        },
        function(){
            $('#top-login-over-logged:visible').slideUp(100);
        }
    );
}); //ready
```

HTML:

```
<div class="absolute" id="top-login">
            <?php if(! isLoggedIn()) : ?>
            <p class="top-login-header">ENTRE<span> ou </span><a href="<?php echo base_url('cadastro'); ?>">CADASTRE-SE</a></p>
            <div id="top-login-over">
                <?php if($this->session->flashdata('loginError')){$loginError = $this->session->flashdata('loginError');} ?>
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('login'); ?>" novalidate>
                    <p><input type="email" name="user_email" value="" placeholder="EMAIL" /></p>
                    <?php if(isset($loginError)){echo $loginError['user_email'];} ?>
                    <p><input type="password" name="user_password" value="" placeholder="SENHA" /></p>
                    <?php if(isset($loginError)){echo $loginError['user_password'];} ?>
                    <p class="clear"></p>
                    <p class="pull-left" id="login-over-esqueci"><a href="#esqueci-minha-senha" role="button" data-toggle="modal">esqueci minha senha</a></p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo current_url(); ?>" />
                    <p class="pull-right"><input type="submit" name="" value="ENTRAR" /></p>
                </form>
                <p class="clear"></p>
                <p id="top-facebook-login"><a href="<?php  echo $login_url; ?>"></a></p>
                <p class="register-reminder ptop15">Ainda não é um membro?</p>
                <p class="register-reminder">Cadastre-se <a href="<?php echo base_url('cadastro'); ?>">aqui</a></p>
            </div>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p class="top-login-header">VOCÊ ESTÁ LOGADO</p>
                <div id="top-login-over-logged">
                    <div class="pull-left" id="top-login-pic">
                    <?php if(!empty($user['thumb'])) : ?>
                    <p><img src="<?php echo $user['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $user['primeiro_nome']." ".$user['sobrenome']; ?>" /><p>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <p><img src="<?php echo base_url('student_images/sample_thumb.png'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $user['primeiro_nome']." ".$user['sobrenome']; ?>" /><p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-left mleft15" id="top-login-info">
                        <p class="julius font14"><?php echo $user['primeiro_nome'];?></p>
                        <p class="font12"><a href ="<?php echo base_url('aluno/meu-perfil'); ?>">Editar Perfil</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div id="top-login-links" class="mtop20">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url('aluno/meu-perfil'); ?>">Meu Perfil</a> | <a href="<?php echo base_url('aluno'); ?>">Meu Campus</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <p id="top-login-logout"><a href="<?php echo base_url("login/logout"); ?>">Sair</a></p>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

The thing is, it's kind of annoying when you're typing your e-mail address and you accidentally move your mouse out of the top-login div. So I want to change it to open when you click. And close when you click again.

Simply changing .hover to .click didn't work. Can you help me with ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `toggle()` instead of `click()`? Click only takes one function, `toggle()` has a similar method signature to `hover()` in that it takes two functions.

Comment: it would be great if u could show us ur HTML

Comment: @nickcoxdotme toggle apparently didn't work

Comment: @MohitBhasi added html code above :)

Comment: Why not add a flag if an input is focused?

Comment: @nick, and grpaiva, the [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event-handling method was removed from jQuery in version 1.9; unless you're using an older version of jQuery, using (that `toggle()` method) is not going to work. The reason it didn't throw an error is because the animation suite also has a [`toggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: @PaulS. I did think about that option, but I'm newbie at this and couldn't figure out how to do it exactly. Could you give me an example? sorry!